# Changing HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, roleprovider

During SetAuthCookie part we are manipulating user name slightly like this

```
string userInfo = identity.Name + "|"  + Util.GetIPAddress();
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userInfo, isPersistent);
```

this is in order to make some checks with users IP Address inside `Application_AuthenticateRequest`

Later on I want to revert the name back to its normal (without "|" and IP address) but couldn't find a way to do it.

Questions I came across generally handled the user name not updating correctly but what I need is to reassign the name.

I tried to set a new cookie and set a new Authcookie but they didnt work, `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` doesn't change.

How can I do this?

Comment: Seems like a XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me - rather than changing your username, tell us what you are trying to do inside `Application_AuthenticateRequest`  that requires the users IP address

Comment: To be honest this was one of my concerns too. Basically we are trying to add the IP to cookie so we can detect IP change and drop the session if same user logins from a different IP. I'm just doing what I'm told.

Answer (score 1):

It is a better aproach to build your own authentication cookie to add the custom values you need, that way you keep the username unchanged wich is more consistent and the expected behavior.

Take into account doing this, you have the userdata (the ip) encrypted in the cookie.

```
    var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(name, rememberMe);
    var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
    var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration,ticket.IsPersistent, userData, ticket.CookiePath);
    var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
    cookie.Value = encTicket;

    //and add the cookie to the current HttpContext.Response
    response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Additionaly, you can retrieve this userData back from the current User.Identity

```
var data = (HttpContext.Current?.User.Identity as FormsIdentity)?.Ticket.UserData
```